# Impersonation on IIS 7.0 passes the machine credentials for Crystal Reports

Tags: iis-7, asp.net, crystalreports, impersonation

On a 32-bit Windows 2008 server running the Donor2 Application in the Classic .NET Managed Pipeline mode, configured for Windows Integrated Authentication and Impersonation, all of the .NET pages are passing the authenticated user’s credentials [DomainName\UserName]. This is the correct, expected behavior. The Crystal Reports pages, instead of passing the authenticated user’s credentials, are passing the IIS Server’s credentials [DomainName\MachineName$].

One of the very frustrating aspects of this situation is that I have another server which, as far as I can tell, is configured identically. That server, when loading Crystal Reports, is passing the authenticated user’s credentials [DomainName\UserName] as expected. I have obviously missed something, but I have no idea what it could be.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that there is apparently an issue with impersonation on the version of Crystal Reports that we were running. We were using Crystal Reports XI R2 SP4. Upgrading to SP6 resolved the issue.